# How to use percent signs with LIKE in a custom Spring Boot N1QL query for use with a Couchbase DB

Tags: java, spring, couchbase, sql++, spring-data-couchbase

I want to pass in a name to the method and have it add the percent signs for me inside the query.

If the Query is `@Query("...file_name LIKE $1 ...")` and I pass in `%dogNames%` it works perfectly.
But what does the Query have to be for me to pass in `dogNames` (no `%`'s) and it works exactly the same?

I am able to do this with `findByFileNameContains()`. The query for `findByFileNameContains()` is auto-generated for me and works so that I can pass in a String like "dogNames.txt" and it will return File's with names like "/bin/dogNames.txt.9348393.tgz" and "/bigdogNames.txt". So it wrote something like this for me: `@Query ("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE file_name LIKE %$1% ")` The percent signs are included in the query and I just pass in the string I want the file name to contain.

How do I write a query myself that performs the same way? I tried what is shown for `findByFileNamePatternAndFileDirectory()` and I get this error:

```
{"msg":"syntax error - at %!(NOVERB)","code":3000}
```

DAO class:

```
import com.mystuff.File;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface FileDao
    extends CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository<File, String> {


  List<File> findByFileNameContains(String fileName);


  @Query(
      "#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE #{#n1ql.filter} AND file_name LIKE %$1% AND  file_dir = $2")
  List<File> findByFileNamePatternAndFileDirectory(
      String fileName, String fileDir);
}
```

More Complete Error Logs:

```
{"msg":"syntax error - at %!(NOVERB)","code":3000}
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate.findByN1QL(CouchbaseTemplate.java:470)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.executeCollection(AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.java:157)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.executeDependingOnType(AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.java:132)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.execute(AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.java:107)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.support.ViewPostProcessor$ViewInterceptor.invoke(ViewPostProcessor.java:87)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find the query that would go in the `@Query("...")` however I did get it to work by using the "query builder mechanism built into Spring Data repository infrastructure" to auto-generate the query for me by naming the method in a specific way:

```
List<File> findByFileNameContainsAndFileDirectory(
      String fileName, String fileDir);
}
```

Here is where I found some good information on how to name the methods to get it to perform the Query you want: [Spring-Data-Couchbase Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details)

And this discusses the SpEL (Spring Expression Language, ex: `#{#n1ql.filter}`) in case you are curious how that works: [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.repository.n1ql)

Answer (score 0):

LIKE can be done only on strings. right hand side of LIKE must  be in quotes. If it is query parameter it may not be optimized

use Some thing like this

file_name LIKE "xyz%"

Comment: If the Query is `@Query("... WHERE file_name LIKE $1...")` and I pass in `%xyz%` it works fine. But what does the Query need to be for me to pass in `xyz` and it works the exact same? Thats what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: U need to decide that what match you want. https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/comparisonops.html.

Comment: If you want to just pass in 'xyz' and not '%xyz%', maybe you can use the concatenate operator in your query? `WHERE file_name LIKE '%' || $1 || '%'`?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
"#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE #{#n1ql.filter} AND file_name LIKE $1 || '%' AND  file_dir = $2")
```